# Verifying business ideas based on keywords derived from a description of the business idea

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification

I want to find keywords for a business idea. The problem is that I have a hard time summarizing the business idea to one to three terms that would describe it.

Is there a (machine learning) tool that takes a description as an input and outputs - intelligently - categories and/or explicit search terms that fit the business idea most likely?

Answer (score 1):

You need keyword extraction technics. Basically they try to find the most important words in the text. There are many types of such methods.